# API to 'Disable downloading, printing, and copying of any Google Drive file'

Tags: google-drive-api

Google released this feature couple of months ago. The link below mentions that it is accessible via API. Tried using drive api patch call to toggle the "disable downloading .." flag which I assume is the "copyable" flag, but to no avail.

https://connect.googleforwork.com/docs/DOC-11088

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: where does it mention its available though the API?

Comment: also your link doesnt work but I remember the feature is only enabled in drive unlimited.

Comment: Pasting the paragraph from the above link:

"To enable this feature, open the sharing dialogue from any Google document, spreadsheet, presentation, or other file in Drive on the web and click on Advanced in the lower right hand corner. Check the ‘Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers’ box and click Save changes. This functionality is also available through API."

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the "labels.restricted" Property.

Here's what you would do it in C#.

```
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
    body.Title = Path.GetFileName(filename);
    body.Labels = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File.LabelsData();

    body.Labels.Restricted = true;

    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    try
    {
            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = 
                 service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
            request.Upload();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
       ExceptionLogger.log(ex);
    }
```

Check out the link below for samples. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy.

Answer (score 0):

`labels.restricted` is deprecated.
You should to set the `copyRequiresWriterPermission` metadata property instead.

Source: [Google Drive API Files Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)